# IIS URL rewrite to access subfolder content

Tags: iis, web-config

Is it possible to create a URL rewrite that places the content of a subfolder in the root?

> ### Example:
>
> /pages/article1 would be reached from /article1
>
> /pages/otherstuff would be reached from /otherstuff

I don't want to use virtual directories, because we're talking about hundreds of static pages in the /pages folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself... This did the trick:

```
<rule name="RemoveSEOFolder" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^seo$|^seo/(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="seo/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteToFile">
    <match url="^(?!seo/)(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="seo/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```